# AsParallel() method is supported in PCL but not available in .NET Standard 1.3?

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library, portability, plinq

the bit of code below does compile fine when sitting within a PCL lib with profile7 (targets: .NET 4.5, Windows 8, .NET Core 1.0, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.IOS, Xamarin.IOS Classic)

However, after converting the PCL project to a .NET Standard 1.3 lib it fails with:

```
error CS1061: 'IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'AsParallel' and no extension method 'AsParallel' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

But .NET Standard 1.3 should still support PLINQ's AsParallel() method, right? 
Perhaps I'm overlooking something? Should there perhaps be an an additional nuget included for PLINQ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PclTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Test()
        {
          List<string> list = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" };

          var result = list.AsParallel().Where(x => x == "foo").ToList();

          System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(result.Count == 1);    
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with all the latest updates

Comment: http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: What @LexLi means is that there is a `System.Linq.Parallel` Package.

Comment: Henk's comment solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a Nuget package called [System.Linq.Parallel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Parallel/) which provides the `AsParallel` method in `PCL`'s